# How to move file to storage? laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to move the uploaded files to my storage folder. It is actually working in image files. But when I try to upload pdf files, it gives me an error below.

**Error**

> fopen(D:\document\My Documents\optodph\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied

**View**

```
<form action="{{ route('upload.files') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input class="file-cpc" type="file" name="file" required>
</form>
```

**In my controller**

```
$filename = auth()->user()->id;
$dir = '/users/',
Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs($dir, $request->file, $filename);
```

Is there something I went wrong? Please help guys.

Comment: try to write it `$request->file->store($dir)`

Comment: @Joseph new error display `The "" file does not exist or is not readable.`

Comment: you have error in your permission check if the place that you upload from this pdf file is readable and give him permission ``775``

Comment: @Joseph "check if the place that you upload" you mean the directory where the file from Sir?

Comment: yah i mean that

Comment: @Joseph actually the place where it from is from *downloads folder*

Comment: change your downloads directory to `775`

Comment: @Joseph the file where it from is  from **C:\Users\beeren\Downloads**. You mean change it to these **C:\Users\beeren\775**?

Comment: no i meant change your permissions to 775

Comment: @Joseph how Sir?

Comment: are you use `windows` or `linux` ?

Comment: @Joseph windows

Comment: i think the problem is with the `/` at the first of your path edit  your dir variable to `users` only

Comment: and try to upload in public like this `$request->file->store('users', 'public')`

Comment: could you tell me which version of laravel you use? because i found an issue on GitHub with the same problem in an old version

Comment: @Joseph 5.8 Sir

Comment: how that !! if you check your issue her it happens alot in windows but in old versions https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23008

Comment: @Joseph I just confused why it is working on the image types, but in document like pdf file. it doesn't

Comment: is this `pdf` file large ?!!

Comment: @Joseph 3.14MB size

Comment: try a small file with `KB` maybe the problem with size

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$path = $request->file->store('users', 'local');
```

No separator required for dir name, 'users/somepath', 'dogs', etc

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L233

routes/web.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('upload/files', function (){
    return view('index');
});
Route::post('upload/files', function (Request $request){
    return $path = $request->file->store('/users/', 'local');
})->name('upload.files');
```

resources/views/index.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('upload.files') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input class="file-cpc" type="file" name="file" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

url: your-domain.test/upload/files

Comment: return $request->file->store('users', 'local');
It`s show the path of file?

Comment: I just confused why it is working on the image types, but in document like pdf file. it doesn't

Comment: Show all controller, mb problem in validation

 protected $validationRules = [
        'file' => 'mimes:jpg,png,gif,jpeg'
    ];

or try set this line after name fucntion like this
function NameStoreMethod (Request $request) {
return $request->file->store('users', 'local');
...

Comment: and bdw does the size matter? because it's 3.14 MB

Comment: Can you add this in you route file?
`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

`Route::post('upload/files', function (Request $request){
    return $path = $request->file->store('users', 'local');
})->name('upload.files');`